# Why at Pokerstars clicking a pot button adds 1000 more?

Tags: texas-hold-em, pre-flop, raise, poker-stars

I played a 250/500 no-limit Hold'em cash game at Pokerstars and noticed the following:

If no one has raised yet, the preflop pot size is ***P*** = 750 (BB + SB). There is a `pot` button, clicking `pot` + `raise` buttons adds (1000 + ***P***) into the pot. If there were 750 chips in the pot, I would add 1750 more. The pot would now be of size 2500 and others would need to add up to 1750 to call.

However, if I click the `3bb` + `raise` buttons, I am only adding 1500 into the pot.

Question: **What is this extra 1000 for?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a pot-sized raise is calculated as follows:

1. Match the standing bet, and then
2. Raise by the size of the pot after you have matched the current bet.

The formula for calculating this is **3x current bet + *dead money***.  Why does this formula work?  Let's use actual numbers so we can see more clearly:

Example 1:  SB posts 250, BB posts 500.  You are UTG and you want to put in a pot-sized raise.  We first match the current bet (**500**), then we calculate the amount in the pot (**500**+**500**+*250*=1250).  The total amount you would put in is therefore 500+1250=1750.

In the above example, the three **500** and the *250* sums to a total of  a pot-sized raise:  1750.

Example 2:  The pot is 1000.  On the flop, SB bets 400.  You in the BB wants to put in a pot-sized raise.  We first match the current bet (**400**), then we calculate the amount in the pot (**400**+**400**+*1000*=1800).  The total amount you would put in is therefore 400+1800=2200.

In the above example, we use the formula **3x400**+*1000*=2200.